# Android: Color looks different on canvas vs views

Tags: android, android-canvas

### Setup

I have the following color resource defined

```
<color name="background">#333333</color>
```

I apply it on a LinearLayout (the root view of an activity):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     ...
     android:background="@color/background">
```

I also apply it as the background of my Surface/Canvas:

```
private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
```

### Result

[image: color difference]

The problem is that the color is darker on the SurfaceView/Canvas than the LinearLayout.

If it matters, the `minSdkVersion: 10` and `targetSdkVersion: 19`

Thanks.

#### Update

Checking the colors that are produced, I determined that the LinearLayout is producing the correct color and the Canvas is darker than it should be. Canvas produced the color `#313131` instead of `#333333`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `SurfaceView` is not being rendered with 32 bit colors.

You will need to get the `SurfaceHolder` for the `SurfaceView`. This can be achieved through `getHolder()` on the view itself.

Then just put it into 32 bit mode with:

`getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);`

Comment: you sir, are a shepherd among sheep.